# systemd[1]: syslog-ng@default.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=7/BUS

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, linux-kernel, syslog-ng

I am using arch-linux. After running 24hr I am getting syslog-ng@default.service core dump.

Log:
systemd[1]: systemd-coredump@1-15223-0.service: Deactivated successfully.

systemd[1]: syslog-ng@default.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=7/BUS

systemd[1]: syslog-ng@default.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.

systemd[1]: syslog-ng@default.service: Consumed 5.777s CPU time.

systemd[1]: syslog-ng@default.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.

systemd[1]: Starting System Logger Daemon "default" instance...

Comment: `SIGBUS` is hardware-related (accessing an invalid memory address). Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212466/what-is-a-bus-error-is-it-different-from-a-segmentation-fault) brings some light.